# Chrome history page: Google search results labelling

Tags: google-chrome, search, history

On the Chrome History page ([chrome://history/](http://chrome://history/)), Google search results show like this:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

This makes finding a previous search hard. I want these entries to be labelled by the keywords I used for the search. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. However, in most recent versions of Chrome you can search using the `Search history` box in the upper right. You can also save items you use a lot in bookmarks. These appear in the `Bookmarks bar` (just below the address box, if enabled) or in `Other bookmarks`. Finally, you can manually remove history items using the little drop-down next to each history item or whole days using `Clear browsing history...` so that only the items of special interest to you remain.

Comment: Good enough to bump my answer +1, please? I'm trying to get enough recommendation to vote for answers myself!